# Javascript não altera a <div>

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou com um problema no meu código em Javascript, estava fazendo um exercício mas o meu código não altera o conteúdo de uma div chamada "res".
Já debuguei o código e deu o seguinte erro:

```
var inicio = document.getElementById('txtinicio')
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Enquanto no navegador não ocorre nenhum erro.

Código em HTML:

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Vamos contar</h1> 
    </header>
    <section>
        <div>
            <p>
                Início: <input type="number" name="txtinicio" id="txtinicio">
            </p>
            <p>  
                Fim: <input type="number" name="txtfim" id="txtfim">
            </p>
            <p>
                Passo: <input type="number" name="txtpasso" id="txtpasso"> <br>
                <br> <input type="button" value="Contar" onclick="verificar()">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="res">
            Preparando a contagem...
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Alex Faustino</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Código em Javascript:

```js
var inicio = document.getElementById('txtinicio')
var fim = document.getElementById('txtfim')
var passo = document.getElementById('txtpasso')
var res = document.getElementById('res')
var inicion = Number(inicio)
var fimn = Number(fim)
function verificar() {
    if (inicio.value.length == 0 && fim.value.length == 0 && passo.value.length == 0) {
        window.alert('[ERRO] Insira os dados!')
    } else {
        for (var c=inicion; c<=fimn; c++) {
            res.innerHTML(c)
        }
    }
}
```

Muito obrigado por toda a ajuda! :)

Comment: voce ja tentou colocar todo o ponto e virgula no final de cada comando? e completar a sua tag script com type="text/javascript"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem problemas diversos no seu código, por exemplo, com o `document.getElementById` é resgatado o `input` e na função precisa ser indicado o seu valor (`input.value`), o teste consequentemente não testa valor e por fim parece que faltou colocar o passo no `for`, bom tentei fazer um exemplo minimo, e imprimir o resultado na tela:

```js
const inicio = document.getElementById('txtinicio')
const fim = document.getElementById('txtfim')
const passo = document.getElementById('txtpasso')
const res = document.getElementById('res')

function verificar() {    
    let ini = parseInt(inicio.value) || 0;  
    let fin = parseInt(fim.value) || 0 ;
    let pas = parseInt(passo.value) || 0;
    let str = '';
    if (ini > 0 && fin > 0 && ini < fin && pas > 0){
      for (var c = ini; c <= fin; c = c + pas) {
        str = str + c + ' ';
      }
      res.innerHTML = str;
    }
    else {
       window.alert('[ERRO] Insira os dados!')
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Início: <input type="number" name="txtinicio" id="txtinicio">
  </p>
  <p>
    Fim: <input type="number" name="txtfim" id="txtfim">
  </p>
  <p>
    Passo: <input type="number" name="txtpasso" id="txtpasso"> <br>
    <br> <input type="button" value="Contar" onclick="verificar()">
  </p>
</div>
<div id="res">
  Preparando a contagem...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar seu código javascript dentro do evento `onload` do documento html, assim você garante que seu javascript só será executado quando todo documento for carregado. Se estiver usando Jquery use a função `reader()` e coloque todo seu código dentro dela.

```
//Jquery
$(document).ready(fucntion(){
    //Seu código aqui.
})

//Javascript puro
document.onload = function(){
    //Seu código aqui.
}
```